# How to use the listView.setEmptyView()?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar

I want to add a progress bar in a listview when the list loads and if there are no results after the loading is finished I  want to add a textVeiw saying the list is empty using the setEmptyView function.
 I tried using this code to add a progress bar in the list but now luck:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
 ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(parent);
         progress.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((ListView) view).setEmptyView(progress);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

how do I add a progress bar in the list pragmatically without using xml layout to inflate it from?
thaks

Comment: Why not use an adapter's getCount() and getView() to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,I am not tried but got the reference from this [Android – ListView => setEmptyView()](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-setemptyview/)

```
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.progressBar));
```

and let me working or not.

Good Luck.